# Increasing a file's size using mmap

Tags: python, linux, mmap, memory-mapped-files

In Python on Windows I can create a large file by

```
    from mmap import mmap
    f = open('big.file', 'w')
    f.close()
    f = open('big.file', 'r+')
    m = mmap(f.fileno(), 10**9)
```

And now `big.file` is (about) 1 gigabyte. On Linux, though, this will return `ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size`.

Is there a way to get the same behavior on Linux as with Windows? That is, to be able to increase a file's size using `mmap`?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but did you try mmap's resize method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On POSIX systems at least, `mmap()` cannot be used to increase (or decrease) the size of a file. `mmap()`'s function is to memory map a portion of a file. It's logical that the thing you request to map should actually exist! Frankly, I'm really surprised that you would actually be able to do this under MS Windows.

If you want to grow a file, just `ftruncate()` it before you `mmap()` it.

Comment: Oh that's useful cause you can shorten a file too. Now I wish Windows had `ftruncate()`!

Comment: Windows does not have `ftruncate()`? Well, that surprises me too :-) Yet surely it must have *some* equivalent method of growing or shrinking files.

Comment: I should say that I'm basing that statement off the Python Docs, not off any Windows documentation.

Comment: For anyone reading in the future, file objects also have a `truncate()` method which works like `os.ftruncte()` accept that it is available on both Windows and Unix. This is useful because Pypy has Unix like behavior for growing a memory mapped file, even on Windows.

Comment: Is there a way to memory map a file, then grow the file and then remap the file? I'm wondering if databases uses memory mapping and is also capable of growing the underlying file.

Comment: @chewsocks: And for people reading further in the future, [Python 3.5 added support for `os.ftruncate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.ftruncate) (and `os.truncate` as well), so you can use whichever one makes sense (`truncate` method if you've already got a file object, `os.truncate`/`os.ftruncate` if you've only got a file descriptor).

Comment: `ftruncate` then remap would be considered as thread/process safe?